# Acer Aspire 7741Z 5731 black screen at boot

Tags: laptop, acer-aspire

From the off state, turning the laptop on causes the screen to turn on, but remains black. The CPU fan is activated, and the air that it is pushing out is warm. There's no acer logo or BIOS POST information. I've removed the battery and HD and turned it on, it continues to do the same thing. Once it is turned on, I don't need to hold the off button to turn it off. All I need to do is just press it.

There are a number of instructions on the internet which suggest that the solution to this problem is to download the BIOS firmware from the acer website and flash the BIOS via USB. I've tried this without success. The process doesn't provide any feedback at all, so it's not clear whether it is even trying to flash the BIOS or not.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've tried reseating the memory sticks. I also tried holding down the power button for 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a display error. You could try connecting a monitor or television to see if there's any output.